# HTML maxlength attribute is not working for composition event in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

With composition input (input with IME) for plain text input field in HTML I can input length exceeding max length. After focusing out the value is truncated. But in Chrome the value is left-shifted as shown in the image.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="text" placeHolder="Maximum support 5" maxlength="5" />
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to limit input length in the case of composition input (IME input)?

Comment: IME input is technically not yet inputted into the page, so you can't really control it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the max attribute instead. It will specify the highest possible number that you may insert

Example:

```
  <input type="number" min="1" max="99999" />
```

Comment: Thanks but in Chrome, this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is weird. As you can see here it works:

```html
<input id="text" placeHolder="Maximum support 5" maxlength="5" />
```

**You can try this:**

- Remove the placeholder.
- Add a `type='text'` in your input.
- Try in a different browser.
- Ensure that you're reloaded the code/tab/browser.
- Clear cache.

Comment: Thanks but in Chrome, this did not solve the problem.